# Member access and template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, template-specialization, member-functions

I have this class template

```
template <typename T>
class Wrapper
{
    public:
        virtual void parse(std::string s) = 0;

    protected:
        T value;
};
```

ideally, each type should know how to parse itself from a string, so I would like to have, for instance, specializations such as

```
template<>
class Wrapper<int> 
{
    public:
        virtual void parse(std::string s) 
        {
            value = atoi(s.c_str());
        }
};
```

however, apparently, I can't access the "value" member from the main template. What I get is something like:

```
In member function 'virtual void Wrapper<int>::parse(std::string)':
error: 'value' is not a member of 'Wrapper<int>'
```

adding `this->` in front of `value` doesn't help.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The various specializations of class template are **completely unrelated** to each other. `Wrapper<int>` does not know anything about e.g. `Wrapper<char>`. So you need to separately define the data members for each specialization

```
template<>
class Wrapper<int> 
{
    public:
        virtual void parse(std::string s) 
        {
            value = atoi(s.c_str());
        }
    protected:
        int value;
};
```

There is also the question of the `virtual` keyword in front of `parse()`. You do not need it here unless you intend `Wrapper<int>` to be a base class that can have its `parse()` method redefine by subsequent derived classes. If all you are going to do is create various `Wrapper<>` specializations, then you should not make `parse()` virtual.

Comment: @tunnuz and similarly about the `protected` keyword here: you do not seem to need it, and in general it is not recommended to have such data anyway. Just make your data `private`.

Comment: hmmm, if the template specialization class would have to re-define all its own data members and methods, I'd doubt why not just write a completely new class?

Answer (score 4):

I think I solved it, the trick is to specialize only the member functions, not the whole class

```
template<>
void Wrapper<int>::parse(std::string s)
{
    this->value = atoi(s.c_str());    
}
```

Comment: this works, but only for full specializations, not for partial specializations (e.g. not for `std::vector<T>`, or `T*`)

Answer (score 0):

While this is a really old question, it might be that you were trying to get the most out of template specialisation - using a number of core objects and methods, with various specialised functions that depend upon the underlying objects.

I am pretty naive with this sort of stuff, so there might be a better way of writing the following, but it works.

```
#include <deque>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T> class Storage {
public:
    T a;
    Storage(T i) : a(i) {}
private:
    template <typename B> void write(B s) {
        cout << "Novel: " << s << "\n";
    }
    template <typename I> void write(deque<I> s) {
        cout << "Deque: ";
        for (auto i: s) {
            cout << i << ",";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    template <> void write(string s) {
        cout << "String: " << s << "\n";
    }
    template <> void write(char s) {
        cout << "Char: " << s << "\n";
    }
    template <> void write(int s) {
        cout << "Int: " << a << "\n";
    }
    template <> void write(float s) {
        cout << "Float: " << a << "\n";
    }
public:
    void write() {
        write(a);
    }
};

int main() {
    Storage<int> a(32);
    Storage<char> b('c');
    Storage<float> c(432.21);
    Storage<deque<int>> d({1,2,3,4});
    a.write();
    b.write();
    c.write();
    d.write();
    return 0;
}
```